# Loading Bitcoin core on Debian

Tags: bitcoin-core

I have a fully updated version of Debian running but get these errors when trying to install core.  Snap installed without errors.  Any way to fix this?  The goal is to use Snap to install Bitcoin-qt

```
penguin:~$ sudo snap install core
error: system does not fully support snapd: cannot mount squashfs image using "squashfs":
       mount: /tmp/sanity-mountpoint-843603917: mount failed: Operation not permitted.
```

Comment: This seems unrelated to Bitcoin. I suggest asking in a system administration or linux focused Q&A site.